# Затемнение при выборе объекта

Tags: css3, html5

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, нужно сделать так же, как на картинке, то есть при выборе определенного набора, весь экран немного темнеет и появляется окно с более подробной информацией. Вопрос: можно ли такое сделать средствами html5 и css3 и если да, то как? А если нет, то в каком направлении идти?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Серьезно? Вы про попапы никогда не слышали что ли?

Comment: Могу конечно и вариант чисто на html+css накидать, но лучше поищите плагин для pop-up'ов.

Comment: @MedvedevDev лучше не запутывать вариантами на html-css)

Comment: @Cheg, согласен, тоже с опытом к этому пришел xDD